# Copying a dynamic array of structs to another dynamic array of structs

Tags: c++

I am trying to copy the contents of a dynamic array of structs to another dynamic array of structs, but I am getting the error, 'invalid array assignment' and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Here is my struct:

```
struct Agent
{
    char name[C_STRING_SIZE];
    int idNum;
    double years;
    char location[C_STRING_SIZE];
};
```

My function:

```
Agent *copyEncryptArray(Agent *agentArr, int numOfAgents)
{
    Agent *encryptArr = new Agent[numOfAgents];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfAgents; i++)
    {
        encryptArr[i].name = agentArr[i].name;
        encryptArr[i].idNum = agentArr[i].idNum;
        encryptArr[i].years = agentArr[i].years;
        encryptArr[i].location = agentArr[i].location;
    }
    
    return encryptArr;
}
```

Ultimately, I am trying to encrypt the contents of the agentArr then copy it to encryptArr but I am just trying to figure out how to copy for now. This is for a course and we have not covered memcpy yet so that is not an option.

Comment: Structures are assignable, copyable, etc, provided proper operators exist to do so. You structure, the default copy-assignment operator will work, so you can just `encryptArray[i] = agentArr[i];` for each slot and be done. Frankly, with C++ you should be using `std::vector<Agent>` for this anyway, which makes nearly all of this irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier than you think.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfAgents; i++)
    encryptArr[i] = agentArr[i];
```

Each value in the array is something that meets all requirements of an "object", and can be copied/moved as a whole. No need to bother copying each member of the `struct`.

Comment: perfect, thank you. But I'm still wondering why what I was originally trying wasn't working, isn't it basically the same thing?

Comment: `name` and `location` are arrays. You cannot copy/move arrays like that in C++. The other mentioned alternative is to replace all the arrays with `std::string`s. or use `std::array`s instead of plain arrays. Those are objects and can also be copied/moved individually. But there's no reason to do that when you can simply copy/move the entire `Agent` object, and if you add another member in there you don't need to remember to update the copy/move code, either.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of `char` arrays. It is assignable and there are more merits including almost unlimited length of string.

```
struct Agent
{
    std::string name;
    int idNum;
    double years;
    std::string location;
};
```

If you are unfortunately forced to use arrays for some reason, you will have to assign each elements.

If it is guaranteed that the contents of the arrays will always be strings (sequences of characters terminated by null-character), you can use [`strcpy()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) to copy them.

(I will show only code for `name`, but `location` should also be treated like this)

```
        strcpy(encryptArr[i].name, agentArr[i].name);
```

If you cannot guarantee this, you should use [`memmove()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) (because `memcpy()` is banned here).

```
        memmove(encryptArr[i].name, agentArr[i].name, sizeof(encryptArr[i].name));
```

If `memmove()` is also unfortunately banned, the last option will be assigning the elements one-by-one.

```
        for (int j = 0; j < C_STRING_SIZE; j++)
        {
            encrypyArr[i].name[j] = agentArr[i].name[j];
        }
```